# Mac OS 7.5.3 Command-Delete

Tags: classic-mac-os

I'm running Mac OS 7.5.3 under Sheepshaver on a Mac mini with Catalina. I remember there was a Command-Delete ability to send files and folders to the trash with the aforementioned keystrokes. What I can't remember is  what it was that enabled this. A Control Panel or Extension or a Utility of some kind? Any clues would be much appreciated.

Comment: My old SE/30 only has 7.1, but if I recall correctly there wasn't anything special you had to do in System 7.6 for command-delete to work, it was a new(ish) command added to the Mac system software. It *might* be that Sheepshaver is not passing the keystrokes along correctly, or that I don't remember correctly, after all, my MacWarehouse tech support days are long behind me...

Comment: Found it! It's a Control Panel called Hidden Finder Features. I knew that if I just kept looking ...